# grep : to look up a valid entry in a log

Tags: grep

Hello everyone I'm having an issue with this script. I've just begun work on it and it is supposed to look for entries previously generated by another script I made.

The gist of the thing is that the log has entries like:

```
makefile_1786878:/home/user/project
```

the format is **filename_inode:/originaldirectory/**

and this script is supposed to take a parameter and look for its exact match in the log

```
    if [ $# -eq 0 ]
        then
                echo "No filename has been provided. Please enter a filename to restore!"
                exit 1
fi
echo You have entered $1
echo Looking for $1 in the list of items deleted by safe_rm...
restoredfile=$(grep ^$1 $HOME/.restore.info)
echo $restoredfile
```

The problem I'm having is, if the user entered "mak" or "make" or "makefi" as a parameter it will incorrectly look up this entry

I want it to specifically get the exact match for this, I don't know how to force grep to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try either one of these and see if it'll work for you:

```
grep -w "makefile"

grep "\<makefile\>"
```

If that work, then just change your grep to:
grep either one of those with the $1 parameter inside.

Comment: unfortunately that did not work. Both of those did not yield a result.
the entry is not seperated by spaces, I think some clever use of regular expression is needed to match the format of my log.

I also dont want grep to mistakingly pull out a positive match if the user enters part of the path name instead of the filename itself.

Comment: Do you specifically have to use grep?

If awk would suffice... you can use this:

    awk -F_ '$1=="makefile"' $HOME/.restore.info

If that work, then you can replace the makefile with your ^$1.

I'll have to dust off my grep book to figure that one out. But I have done grep searches into columns before. I just can't recall exactly.

The downside to this is if there's an underscore in the file name, it will only search the first half.